# sed string not matching. Why?

Tags: sed

I'm looking to match any string that contains a `[DEBUG]` statement and that eventually will have a `": "` string following it. If there are several `": "` strings following it, I want to match the first. The idea is to then color both the `[DEBUG]` statement and what's next to the first `": "`.

An example would be:

```
  [thread1] [DEBUG] [2017.03.12 23:22:12] com.abc.def.Xyz: some log message: some more specific info.
```

should be translated into:

```
  [thread1] ${RED}[DEBUG]${DEFAULT} [2017.03.12 23:22:12] com.abc.def.Xyz: ${RED}some log message.${DEFAULT}
```

For that, I thought the following sed replace string would suffice, but it doesn't:

```
sed -r "s/(\[DEBUG\])([^:]*: )(.*)$/${RED}\1${DEFAULT}\2${RED}\3{$DEFAULT}/"
```

I've lost hours around this but unfortunately it doesn't match the shown above string. Any clues on why?

Comment: And what happens to the messages after the 2nd ":". You are showing them deleted whereas you are talking that only the 1st message after ":" is colored, which implies that the 2nd onwards would be left as is. There is an ambiguity here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match, for group 2, anything except a `:` up to a `:`, but there are colons in the time, so you don't match.  You can try replacing the `[^:]` with `.` and likely get the same results, unless you have a `:` somewhere else in the line, then it will match up until the last occurrence of that string.

Perhaps a better pattern, though, is

```
sed -r 's/(\[DEBUG])( \[[[:digit:].: ]*] [^:]*: )(.*)/${RED}\1${DEFAULT}\2${RED}\3${DEFAULT}/'
```

Comment: There are other :'s but they aren't followed by a space, so they should be discarded by the regexp engine. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Consider this case: `echo a:b: xyz | sed 's/[^:]: /worked/'` where it doesn't get confused by having other :s.

Comment: @devouredelysium Right, but you're trying to anchor it so that it's immediately following the `DEBUG` block, and there is no such sequence of non-colon characters then a colon space immediately after the `[DEBUG]`

Comment: Ah, I get your point. I was looking at [^:] as an alternative to the non-greedy operator that sed does not provide..

Comment: `s/(\[DEBUG])( \[[[:digit:].: ]*] [^:]*: )(.*)` should have been `s/(\[DEBUG])( \[[[:digit:].: ]*] [^:]*: )([^:]*)` since only the first log message is to be colored.

Comment: I ended up using Perl, which has a lot more powerful and cleaner regexp flavor.